# How to reduce flickering with Unity and Socket.IO?

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine, socket.io, multiplayer, flicker

i'm currently trying to create a simple multiplayer game with Unity and Socket.IO. However at the moment i'm facing some problems. When i passed the positional data to my nodejs server everything got messed up, because Unity decided to use a comma "," instead of a dot "." when handling floats. I worked around that problem by setting my culture zone in the start function to en-US:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

By doing that i received the correct data on the server. But when sending the data to other users they receive wrong numbers. For example: Player 1 changes x position to 1.23 -> other players receive 123 as the x value. Again i tried to fixed this and just divided the value by 100.
Now i can move a player and the others will see him moving to the correct position. But now the player model is just flickering. Only when it stands still, it ist completely there. I'm not sure if this is a mistake in my code, or just a Unity bug, or a result of the way i open the same Unity project twice (Symlink). I hope someone has an idea of what's going on in my project.

Flickering:
[image]

**Edit:**
Server-side code:

```
socket.on('updatePosition', (data) => {
    player.position.x = data.position.x;
    player.position.y = data.position.y;
    player.position.z = data.position.z;

    socket.broadcast.emit('updatePosition', player);
});
```

Unity code for sending new positions:

```
player.position.x = MethodExtensions.twoDecimals(transform.position.x);
player.position.y = MethodExtensions.twoDecimals(transform.position.y);
player.position.z = MethodExtensions.twoDecimals(transform.position.z);

networkIdentity.getSocket().Emit("updatePosition", new JSONObject(JsonUtility.ToJson(player)));
```

Unity code for receiving new data:

```
On("updatePosition", (E) => {
    string id = MethodExtensions.removeQuotes(E.data["id"].ToString());
    float x = E.data["position"]["x"].f / 100.0f;
    float y = E.data["position"]["y"].f / 100.0f;
    float z = E.data["position"]["z"].f / 100.0f;

    NetworkIdentity networkIdentity = serverObjects[id];
    networkIdentity.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
});
```

Comment: From the gif it seems like this Flickr occurs because you get weird position data.

Comment: I thought that too, but i checked the positions passed to my object and they seem to be correct.

Comment: Did you log positions of object and data from network as well. Maybe some frames you do not get data and assign `(0,0,0)` position. Also it would help if you can share your code.

Comment: Your completely right. I just checked my positions again and didn't notice that sometimes the rounded positions i send to the server only have one decimal place. And on the other side i divide them by 100 to work against that weird behavior of Unity. I assume that my server sends the correct data. However i'm using a socket.io extension in unity and don't really know where do log the positions, received from the server.

Comment: Well i suspect it can be a syncronization problem. Maybe you can save position in last frame and wont move the object if there is big difference between received data and last frame position.

Comment: The weird thing is that my server receives data for example: x=2.31 and in unity i get back x=231. So i decided to divide all those values by 100. But i didn't think about the possibility that my server would send something like x=2.3 so in unity 23 -> /100 = 0.23. My main problem there is that either my server when sending or unity when receiving the positions ignores the dot.

Comment: Well it is a problem. A workaround might be dividing the number to 100 and checking if result is bigger than 0. Also same thing for 10.

Comment: I don't think that will work. For example the real position could be 2.3, unity receives 23. But also 0.23 will be 23 in unity.

Comment: Ah you are right? Can you send the data as string and use string.split? For splitting integer and decimal part

Comment: Maybe. I figured out, that the proplem is the conversion of a string to a JSONObject in unity. It happens when the socket.io asset decodes the send data. There i also saw that the data my server sends is indeed correct. Now i just have to find out what is wrong with the new JSONObject(String) function, because it seems to ignore floats.

Comment: I found the solution. When the JSONObject function converts the string it takes your culture into account. Since i'm not from the US or anywhere else where floats are written with a dot, it wasn't able to convert the the number and just ignored the comma. Now it's working perfectly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad you solved the issue.